# Unable to retain background-image

Tags: html, css

I have a button which is actually a div posing as a button. On hover of the div i change the background to a gradient background. However the gradient is overlapping a background image that i have originally. How can i retain the original bg-image.

I have attached a fiddle demo at the end of the question.

```
 <div class="cart-btn"><a href="">CART</a></div>
```

CSS

```
.cart-btn{
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:2px;
    width:120px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#0396C2;
    border-radius:3px;
    background-image: url(http://www.thorlabs.com/images/newhp/shopping_cart2.png) ;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.cart-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid #005387;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0396C2),   color-stop(100%,rgba(0,76,158,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */       
    margin-top:1px;
}
.cart-btn a{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block;
        line-height: 34px;
        outline: medium none;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/rbqTb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you have to give the background link of image again on hover.

```
    .btn:hover{
    background: url('url of the image') no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0396C2), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,76,158,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */ ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following css...

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbqTb/2/)

```
.cart-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid #005387;
    background: url(http://www.thorlabs.com/images/newhp/shopping_cart2.png) no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0396C2), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,76,158,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */       
    margin-top:1px;

}
```